# How to handle a request with HTTPS protocol in Tornado?

Tags: https, python-2.7, tornado

I'm a newbie in Tornado. And I begin my learning with “Hello World" code like this:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver

class HelloHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world!")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", HelloHandler)
])

http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server.listen(80)
    # http_server.listen(443)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

When I entered "http://localhost" at the browser, it works and prints

```
"Hello, world!"
```

But if I tried the request "https://localhost", it returns with:

```
Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED): The server refused the connection.
```

There are too little documents about Tornado online, who can tell me how to deal with Https protocol request?

Comment: Have you generated the required certificates/key files etc? There's much much more to HTTPS then just "S".

Comment: Generate certificates/key files? I think I have long way to go.. and I'll google the concept first.

Comment: Hi @PaulC Thank you for your suggestion. I've installed openssl and generate my own key&crt. And also thanks to demikl , after adding key&crt to the ssl_options, my Hello World program works! :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [`tornado.httpserver` documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/httpserver.html#tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer), you need to pass `ssl_options` dictionary argument to its constructor, then bind to the HTTPS port (443) :

```
http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(applicaton, ssl_options={
    "certfile": os.path.join(data_dir, "mydomain.crt"),
    "keyfile": os.path.join(data_dir, "mydomain.key"),
})

http_server.listen(443)
```

`mydomain.crt` should be your SSL certificate, and `mydomain.key` your SSL private key.

Comment: Note that you can easily create another non-SSL instance if you want to. (At least to redirect users from HTTP to HTTPS.)